# Session -> eMail / Problems

Tags: php, arrays, email, session

Session -> eMail / Problems

Hey guys. So im storing a whole array in a session. There is a basket which spits it out (via foreach), that works fine. Now there is form where the person that orders puts information in. These information + the array i want send to an eMail. Sending information from the form, no problem. Sending both doesnt work.

**Array out**

```
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
 {
 $total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
{
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="4" color="black"><font-family="Cambria,        Georgia, serif">';
echo ''.$cart_itm["qty"].'';
...
```

**Form an eMail Script**

```
....
$name = $_POST["name"];
...
$message = 'Hello '.$name.'<br>'
$message .= '  **HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE ARRAY TO SHOW UP** '
...
```

Any ideas? Cheers